# How to change keyboard layout( e.g. QWERTY , DVORAK) in KDE 5 from command-line?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

How to change keyboard layout in command-line in KDE 5 , Kubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Google search on "KDE change keyboard layout" shows https://www.librebyte.net/en/desktop/change-keyboard-layout-in-kde/

Comment: Dear @K7AAY , I already know that .I want to do this in command-line(via qdbus , kwriteconfig or so).

Answer (score 0):

The command to change keyboard layout in KDE Plasma 5 is:

```
qdbus org.kde.keyboard /Layouts setLayout "xyz"
```